# SQL statement: how can I pick a value only once from a table to update another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I wish to update table1 with any distinct value of table2 matching the same code, no matter which one or the order (value from table2 can't be picked more than once)

```
+-------------------+      +--------------+
|      table1       |      |    table2    |
+-------------------+      +--------------+
| id | code | value |      | code | value |
+----+------+-------+      +------+-------+
| 1  |  A   |       | <--  |  A   |  v1   |
| 2  |  A   |       |      |  B   |  v2   |
| 3  |  B   |       |      |  A   |  v3   |
+----+------+-------+      |  A   |  v5   |
                           |  A   |  v6   |
                           +------+-------+
+-------------------+                      
|      table1       |                      
+-------------------+                      
| id | code | value |
+----+------+-------+
| 1  |  A   |  v6   |
| 2  |  A   |  v3   |
| 3  |  B   |  v2   |
+----+------+-------+
```

How can I write the SQL update statement ?
(MySQL 5.7)

Comment: Why haven't you picked v1 ? Do you have access to latest MySQL version (8.0.2 and above) ?

Comment: Because the order doen't matter. MySQL 5.7 here

Comment: Can you provide a DB Fiddle or SQL fiddle. I can try to optimize the posted solution further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement provided by [Madhur Bhaiya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2469308/madhur-bhaiya) does work if

1. **@rn* are initialized to 1 instead of 0** (otherwise row_num* are numbered 1 twice)
2. **the SELECT from table2 is DISTINCT** (because pairs of (code,value) are repeated in table2)

The statement should be

```
UPDATE 
table1 AS t1 

JOIN 

(SELECT 
   dt1.id, 
   IF(@cd1 = dt1.code, @rn1 := @rn1 + 1, 1) AS row_num1, 
   @cd1 := dt1.code AS code,
 FROM (SELECT id, code FROM table1 ORDER BY code, id) AS dt1
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn1 := 1, @cd1 := '') AS init1
) AS t2 
  ON t2.id = t1.id 

JOIN 

(SELECT 
   IF(@cd2 = dt2.code, @rn2 := @rn2 + 1, 1) AS row_num2, 
   @cd2 := dt2.code AS code, 
   dt2.value 
 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT code, value FROM table2 ORDER BY code) AS dt2
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn2 := 1, @cd2 := '') AS init2
) AS t3 
  ON t3.row_num2 = t2.row_num1 AND 
     t3.code = t2.code 

SET t1.value = t3.value
```

Comment: Regarding first point, row number will initialized to 1 for different code values, and I believe that is what was needed. Perhaps though, without looking at complete data, and hence SQL / DB fiddle, it is hard to figure out your actual requirements.

Comment: row_num is actually initialized to 1 for different code with `if(..., ..., 1)`, that is ok, but for next same code row_num is 1 again with `if(..., @rn:=@rn+1, ...)` if @rn is initialized to 0

Answer (score 1):

This requires [`Row_Number()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) Window function's magic! Unfortunately, your MySQL version is 5.7; so a more verbose solution using [User-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) follows:

```
UPDATE 
table1 AS t1 

JOIN 

(SELECT 
   dt1.id, 
   IF(@cd1 = dt1.code, @rn1 := @rn1 + 1, 1) AS row_num1, 
   @cd1 := dt1.code AS code 
 FROM (SELECT id, code FROM table1 ORDER BY code, id) AS dt1
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn1 := 0, @cd1 := '') AS init1
) AS t2 
  ON t2.id = t1.id 

JOIN 

(SELECT 
   IF(@cd2 = dt2.code, @rn2 := @rn2 + 1, 1) AS row_num2, 
   @cd2 := dt2.code AS code, 
   dt2.value 
 FROM (SELECT code, value FROM table2 ORDER BY code) AS dt2
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn2 := 0, @cd2 := '') AS init2
) AS t3 
  ON t3.row_num2 = t2.row_num1 AND 
     t3.code = t2.code 

SET t1.value = t3.value
```

You can check the explanation of a similar technique in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53148465/2469308).

Comment: This doesn't work, not because of the extra comma in `@cd1 := dt1.code AS code,
 FROM (SELECT id` but because it repeats value of table2. How about sorting by table2.code and using a variable to skip used value ?

Comment: @guigoz I have fixed the syntax error. Can you please try to provide a https://www.db-fiddle.com/  This will help me in playing with the data and optimize as well as fix the logic further.

Answer (score 0):

use join ,As order does not matter so i think your sample output could be changed

```
    UPDATE table1 a 
    JOIN table2 b ON a.code= b.code 
    set a.value = b.value
```

Comment: And how will this ensure that same value is not repeated ?

Answer (score 0):

Using OVER functions should work:

**Example queries:**

```
select id,code,value,rank() over (partition by code order by id asc) rank_ 
from dbo.table1;

select code,value,dense_rank() over (partition by code order by code,value asc) rank_ from dbo.table2;
```

**Update statment:**

```
UPDATE t 
SET t1.value = t2.value 
FROM (select id,code,value,rank() over (partition by code order by id asc) rank_ from dbo.table1) t1
inner join ( select code,value,dense_rank() over (partition by code order by code,value asc) rank_ from dbo.table2 ) t2
on t1.code = t2.code and t1.rank_ = t2.rank_
```